# WPF C#: this.Resources always contains 0 elements?

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

In my WPF C# application, I have included an executable file (.EXE) into the project, and set its build action to "Resource". Then, I have dragged the file from the solution explorer into the Resources.resx file under "Properties".

However, when I trigger the following code, it displays 0, because there this.Resources contains 0 elements. How come? What exactly am I doing wrong here?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace Application
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : System.Windows.Application
    {

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {

            base.OnStartup(e);

            MessageBox.Show(this.Resources.Count + "");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Application.Resources`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.resources.aspx) are completely disconnected from the resources you can add to your project. Those resources can be accessed via `ApplicationAssemblyNameHere.Properties.Resources`.